# I can't see android animation even though I get notification it has ended

Tags: android, xml, animation, view

I've been trying to use animation on my Android View - first using normal animation, then using a LayoutAnimationController.  The code in `onAnimationEnd()` executes, but I don't see anything moving on screen.

This is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate>
        android:toXDelta="50%"` android:duration="3000" android:fillAfter="true"
    </translate>
</set>
```

This the Java code:

```
loginLayOut = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.login_view);

Animation RightToLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.login_screen_animation);
LayoutAnimationController layoutAnimationController = new LayoutAnimationController(RightToLeft);
loginLayOut.setLayoutAnimation(layoutAnimationController);

if (RightToLeft != null) {
    RightToLeft.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {@
        Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @
        TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)@ Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            loginLayOut.clearAnimation();


            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                loginLayOut.getWidth(), loginLayOut.getHeight());
            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            //lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            lp.removeRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            loginLayOut.setLayoutParams(lp);
            Log.d("Animate", "View has animated");

        }

        @
        Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });


    loginLayOut.startAnimation(RightToLeft);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `The animations fire off`

Comment: I don't see anything move - I'd assume I should see the view move.

Comment: Sorry I meant - The animation fires off in the sense that the code in onAnimationEnd() executes, but I don't see anything.

Comment: can you post your animation.xml?